# PHP not recognized by server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been looking at this issue for a few hours. I looked at many Stackoverflow posts, and I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

I scrapped my website a few months ago, and just started a new one shortly thereafter. However, my website does not seem to accept PHP. I don't know if the issue is with the server (when I renewed my hosting), or something else. Even calling an external PHP file, using the include function, does not work.

Anyhow, after placing the following code (along other simple coding), I see this in my PHP file when I browse the source code - meaning PHP is not working:

```
<?php phpinfo() ; ?>
```

Also, my htaccess file says the following (but I honestly have no clue what any of it means. Though I always hear people say that this file can make a difference:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: if you are using `php` code inside `.html` file then it will not work

Comment: `in my HTML file` is a typo or you are trying to execute PHP from a `.html`?

Comment: Can't you call it from an external source? I couldn't really find much information and I find the php website to be terrible for non-php users. In any case, I thought w3schools was calling it from within an external php page?:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_include1

Comment: Wow, I must have been pretty tried. I just re-read my post above Alive to Die/chris, and it made no sense XD. To answer Chris' question, yes. Typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand what the actual cause is. Do you run your own webserver? If so, is it apache httpd or IIS? If you have an external hosting partner, they should be able to help you.

Why do you have a htaccess file? You only need it for things like redirect rules. If you don't use that, delete this file or empty it.

Installation of LAMP stacks :https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Everything is externally hosted. I looked at the php, and it's on. Also, a standalone php file would work correctly. As for the htaccess file, it was created via wordpress I assume.

Comment: Do you know what webserver your hosting partner is using? I have had problems with mine who hosted via IIS, especially when trying to use htaccess files. I had to use IIS web config files for redirects. When I tried htaccess files, the webserver behaved very strangely.

Comment: I was looking online to see if there was a place for me to figure it out, but no. Although, I was reading that the IIS one should have an icon somewhere. I assume, that since it's not where it should be, that I might have Apache. So, I decided to look around to see if I could make sure I good make sure. However, it says that if you're sharing a server (and don't have a dedicated one), you wouldn't have access to it :/ The onley file you'd have access to would be the htaccess file

Comment: Ok, let's assume it is Apache httpd. You need to know whether the php-module is running. You can check this with your hostingpartner. Just to be sure: php files need to have the php extension. So your sample php file containing <? php phpinfo(); ?> must be called index.php (or checkphp.php or whatever).

Comment: Sounds about right! Thanks for taking the time to write this response :) Much appreciated Ceesiebo!